# Unable to connect to AWS Aurora Serverless with SSL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, ssl, serverless, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm working with [AWS Aurora Serverless V1](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/aurora/serverless/) (with Postgres engine) and I'm trying to connect using [node-postgres](https://node-postgres.com). I was able to connect without SSL perfectly, but when I add the SSL config at the pg client I keep receiving this error:

```
{
    "message": "unable to get local issuer certificate",
    "stack": "Error: unable to get local issuer certificate\n    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1497:34)\n    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)\n    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)\n    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:932:8)\n    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:706:12)"
}
```

This is how the SSL config object is been declared

```
const ca = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----`

module.exports = {
  rejectUnauthorized: true,
  ca,
  checkServerIdentity: (host, cert) => {
    const error = tls.checkServerIdentity(host, cert)
    if (
      error &&
      !cert.subject.CN.endsWith('.rds.amazonaws.com')
    ) {
      return error
    }
  }
}
```

I am downloading the certificate directly from Amazon https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Aurora Serverless docs say that SSL is enforced by default, so I think I'm doing all the neccesary things to make the connection right, but it isn't working though. Maybe there is something about "serverless connections" that work differently from classic ones and I'm not understanding it.